# apache poi guide to custom formats

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is there a guide on how to use custom formats for cells in apache poi?

I have a vague idea on how basic formats work such as `$#,##0.00` producing outputs like `$1,000.00` as described [here](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFDataFormatter.html).

However upon looking at [this](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/LoanCalculator.java) example I saw something this: `wb.createDataFormat().getFormat("_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* \"-\"??_);_(@_)")`

which I cant make heads or tails of.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a general Excel format string, and nothing Apache POI specific. Did you try looking up help files / tutorials on Excel format strings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as stated by @Gagravarr above, these are not poi specific. this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/number-format-codes-HP005198679.aspx) should help anyone else having problems with this

Comment: down voted for being link only to a broken link.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late, but it might help someone else. You find more details and examples here:

**CellFormat** javadoc
 - https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/format/CellFormat.html

**DataFormatter**
 - https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html

Comment: Please summarize the content of the links in your answer, to make it complete on its own. External content might go offline or change, making your answer outdated for other users that might need it.